# How do you switch between parents without the location being affected

Tags: constraints, parent

[image]

I used these object constraints to switch parents but the location is being messed up whenever the influence changes

Comment: if you plan to animated an object that goes from a parent to another, look for the Dynamic Parent addon, it simplifies the operation

Comment: alright i'll try it